# Using a button as a link in HTML (form ASP.Net MVC 3)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

My input pages have an OK and a Cancel button on them.  These buttons are generated in a separate, partial view.  The OK button is the submit for the form.  The Cancel is a link to a different action.  I can't make the Cancel button into a standard:

`<form><input value="Cancel"></form>`

as this would end up with nested forms which doesn't work (The form is on the outer, master view).
I can use Javascript, but I was hoping to have a page that would work without it.
I tried:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("DoStuff")"><button type="button">Stuff</button></a>
```

This works fine on Firefox, but does nothing on IE.  Am I missing something here?  Is there a simple way to get a button to work as a hyperlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make the cancel button submit the form and make the redirect on the server side

Comment: I was trying to avoid this, as it means the submit method has to handle the cancel.  However, I have decided to use this method.

Answer (score 0):

you could CSS-style your link to look like a button.

Comment: This runs the risk of the Cancel button looking different if the platform style changes for normal buttons.  It's also messy getting the press effect.